# C Switch Statement outputs two cases

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
char newr;
lol:
scanf("%c", &newr);


switch (newr) {
case 'a':
    goto killswitch;

case 'b':
    printf("You entered %c", newr);
    goto lol;
    break;
default:
    printf("you entered something other than a or b\a\n");
    goto lol;
    break;
killswitch:
    printf("ayyyy!");
    goto lol;
    break;
}
```

My problem is that when I run the program and I type in a character, lets say in this case a, it gives me the following result:

```
ayyyy!you entered something other than a or b
```

This always happens no matter what the character I input, for example if I input l, it will return this:

```
you entered something other than a or b
you entered something other than a or b
```

I am very confused. Does anyone know the cause of this?

Thanks

Comment: You should never have a goto before a break, and you should (almost) never have labels inside a switch statement. But that isn't the cause of our problem.

Comment: sign the petition to kill the `goto`

Comment: @david.pfx I was just experimenting to see if I could get the program to work, but nevertheless that is something I will keep in mind. Thanks

Comment: @bolov: I write a goto in C/C++ about 1 in every 100K LOC. When you need one, you really, really need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep hitting enter. Since enter is something other than `a` or `b`, your program correctly indicates this.

If you type "ab" your program should indicate that it received an `a`, a `b`, and somehing other than an `a` or `b`.

Comment: I see, thank you! Then can you tell me how to press enter so that the computer ignores the keystroke?

Comment: @AndrewHu It depends on exactly what you want to do. You could add another `case` to ignore enters. You could add a second `scanf` (and ignore the result) to skip the enter.

Comment: @AndrewHu After the scanf() call, add a call to getchar(), where you discard the line feed character that comes from pressing enter.

Comment: @AndrewHu If this solved your problem, you should accept David's answer as the correct one by pressing the big check mark to the left of his post. Also consider giving it an upvote, since it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Remove goto lol;

```
killswitch:
printf("ayyyy!");
break;
```

Comment: However, if I removed the goto lol; then the program would not be able to loop.

Comment: @AndrewHu So we use while() loops to loop instead of goto. You could put the whole thing in a do while and have while character entered != (some exit character). That way you have an exit as well as avoid use of goto. WE DO NOT USE GOTO.

Comment: @Kartik_Koro Lol is there a movement against goto? Will consider

Comment: @AndrewHu It is not considered a good practice. Having multiple exits in a block of code generally makes you spend time in making sure that all exits are properly exited from ( eg, all exits lead to deallocation of dynamically allocated resources) . http://xkcd.com/292/

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (newr) {
case 'a':
goto killswitch;
```

and prints "ayyy!"

then then it moves to 'scanf'

and the enter you pressed it took as '\n' and again goes into the switch.

Comment: Yes, I was told that the solution was to add a getchar(); after the scanf();. Thank you for your help though

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for this problem is to change only one statement slightly.

change

```
scanf("%c", &newr);
```

to

```
scanf("\n%c", &newr);
```

and your program will work as you want now!